# how to join with different tables based on value

Tags: mysql, join

i have 4 tables...the parent table is  d_checkupinfo and i want to join it with (checkup) or (surgery) or (medicaleq) based on  checkupinfo.move_type column value...if it value = 1 then join with checkup table and if value =2 then join with surgery and if value =3 then join with medicaleq.
so how to do this

```
SELECT
  d_checkupinfo.*,
  d_branch.*,
  d_checkup.* ,
  d_surgery.* ,
  d_medicaleq.* ,
  d_patient.*
FROM d_checkupinfo
  LEFT JOIN d_branch WHERE d_checkupinfo.chi_branch_id = d_branch.branch_id
  LEFT JOIN d_patient WHERE d_checkupinfo.chi_pi_num = d_patient.pi_id
  LEFT JOIN d_checkup WHERE d_checkupinfo.chi_type_id = d_checkup.checkup_id AND move_type = 1
  LEFT JOIN d_surgery WHERE d_checkupinfo.chi_type_id = d_surgery.surgery_id AND move_type = 2
  LEFT JOIN d_medicaleq WHERE d_checkupinfo.chi_type_id = d_medicaleq.medicaleq_id AND move_type = 3
```

Comment: Not having a data set I cannot be sure but I suspect the query you posted will work if you change the inner joins to left joins (and changed the clauses to ON rather than WHERE in the joins). If you need to then whittle the results to those that exist in d_checkup/d_surgery/d_medicaleq you can add a where clause IE WHERE (d_checkup.column is not null or d_surgery.column is not null or d_medicaleq.column is not null)

Comment: You forgot the `ON`s for *each* `JOIN` .. `WHERE` is not `ON` and there should only be *one* `WHERE` clause per `SELECT`. The MySQL error *which you should read and report* will say about as much (and maybe more).

Comment: change it still not work

Comment: "You forgot the ONs" .. "There should only be *one* WHERE clause per SELECT" .. "The MySQL error **which you should read and report** will say about as much"

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html - the join condition (ON, USING) is *required* for a LEFT join (and really should be specified for an INNER join as it is only a MySQL "quirk" that allows it to be optional).

Comment: ok it is easy to change from where to on but how to join with condition ???

Comment: With "ON". Take some time to go read a few tutorials (and possibly the link provided). Start with a simpler (eg. 2-table INNER JOIN) before moving to 2-INNER + LEFT any other combinations. Familiarize yourself with the syntax (which is *wrong*, as shown) and understand error messages. The syntax must follow well-defined rules and can't be made up; random guesses / changes are unlikely to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  d_checkupinfo.*,
  d_branch.*,
  d_checkup.* ,
  d_patient.*
FROM d_checkupinfo
  LEFT JOIN d_branch ON d_checkupinfo.chi_branch_id = d_branch.branch_id 
  LEFT JOIN d_patient ON d_checkupinfo.chi_pi_num = d_patient.pi_id 
  LEFT JOIN d_checkup ON d_checkupinfo.chi_type_id = d_checkup.checkup_id WHERE move_type = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT
  d_checkupinfo.*,
  d_branch.*,
  d_surgery.* ,
  d_patient.*
FROM d_checkupinfo
  LEFT JOIN d_branch ON d_checkupinfo.chi_branch_id = d_branch.branch_id
  LEFT JOIN d_patient ON d_checkupinfo.chi_pi_num = d_patient.pi_id
  LEFT JOIN d_surgery on d_checkupinfo.chi_type_id = d_surgery.surgery_id WHERE move_type = 2
UNION ALL
SELECT
  d_checkupinfo.*,
  d_branch.*,
  d_medicaleq.* ,
  d_patient.*
FROM d_checkupinfo
  LEFT JOIN d_branch ON d_checkupinfo.chi_branch_id = d_branch.branch_id
  LEFT JOIN d_patient ON d_checkupinfo.chi_pi_num = d_patient.pi_id
  LEFT JOIN d_medicaleq on d_checkupinfo.chi_type_id = d_medicaleq.medicaleq_id WHERE move_type = 3
```